# ngIf-else in template

Tags: angular, if-statement

I'm trying to load `pictureA` or `pictureB`.
My first solution is like this:

```
 <img *ngIf="my_picture" src="{{my_picture}}" width="180" height="80" >
 <img *ngIf="default_picture && !my_picture" src="{{default_picture}}">
```

But I would like to use `if`-`else` like on API Reference:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">...</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>...</ng-template>
```

So, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
 <div *ngIf="my_picture; else elseBlock">
     <img src="{{my_picture}}" >
 </div>
 <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <img src="{{default_picture}}" >
 </ng-template>
```

But I'm getting a big exception stack trace:

> ```
> zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'ngIfElse' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
>         -->
>
>         <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf="my_picture; else elseBlock">
>             <img src="{{my_picture}}"): UserComponent@15:13
> Property binding ngIfElse not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
> ```
>
> all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
>               -->
>
> ```
>         [ERROR ->]<div *ngIf="my_picture; else elseBlock">
>             <img src="{{my_picture}}" width="180" height="8"): UserComponent@15:8
> 'ng-template' is not a known element
> ```

How can I implement a simple `if`-`else` block?

Comment: Are you using Angular4?

Comment: Why not use `ngSwitch` instead?

Answer (score 10):

You should be using ng-template

```
<ng-template #loading>Failed to do something wrong...</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="userObservable;else loading;">
  Aravind is here
</div>
   <button (click)="userObservable = !userObservable">Click to toggle</button>
</div>
```

**[LIVEDEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yKkGICTxnieDnMws8BtS?p=preview)**

Comment: yes, i've already tried this. But i get this error:

SyntaxError Error: Template parse errors:
'ng-template' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-template' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-template' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: which version of angular ur using?

Answer (score 9):

ngIf/Else syntax is not available in angular 2 but is available in angular 4

For angular 2, you need to use ngIf two times, and in second time you negate the value being compared (not using the !=, but having ampersand with the value)

```
<div class="text-center" *ngIf='userName'> Hello {{userName}}, how are you </div> 
<div class="text-center" *ngIf='userName == ""'> Hello, please login to access the app</div>
```

For angular 4 onwards

```
<div *ngIf="userName; else showLoginRequestMessage">
  Hello {{userName}}, how are you 
</div> 
<ng-template #showLoginRequestMessage>
 <div class="text-center"> Hello, please login to access the app</div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
**example 1 ngIf**

   <div *ngIf="condition">..</div>
   <div template="ngIf condition">..</div>

**example 1.i ngIf**
   <ng-template [ngIf]="condition"><div>..</div></ng-template>

**example 2 else block**

   <div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">....</div>
   <ng-template #elseBlock>....</ng-template>

**example 3 then and else block** 

   <div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
   <ng-template #thenBlock>......</ng-template>
   <ng-template #elseBlock>......</ng-template>
```