# if else inside <ng-template> in angular4

Tags: angular

How to write if else in

```
<select #filterBy (change)="someMethod(filterBy.value)>
<ng-template [ngIf]="condition; else elsePart">
 <option>option1</option>
 <option>option2</option>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elsePart>
 <option>option3</option>
 <option>option4</option>
</ng-template>
</select>
```

Above code gives me an error, i need if condition without any div or span tag. Inside component i am using element reference as

```
 @ViewChild('filterBy') filterBy: ElementRef;
```

Error: Template parse errors:
Binding expression cannot contain chained expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 ngIf-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560088/angular2-ngif-else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; then truePart else elsePart"></div>
<ng-template #truePart>
  <select>
    <option>option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
  </select>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elsePart>
  <select>
    <option>option3</option>
    <option>option4</option>
  </select>
</ng-template>
```

**Original answer:**

> I don't think that's possible, but this link will help you out 
>   https://coursetro.com/posts/code/52/Trying-out-the-New-Angular-4-If-Else-Conditionals
>
> ```
> <div *ngIf="title; then logout else login"></div>
>
> <ng-template #login>Please login to continue.</ng-template>
> <ng-template #logout>Hi Gary, <button>Logout now</button>.</ng-template>
> ```

Comment: @sudheerKB You can just do the same thing, but with the `<select>` instead of the `<div>` I think 

Comment: @sudheerKB I changed my answer as well 

Comment: @MichaelDeBoey What about [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541969/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-6)?