# Angular 5 hide button after clicked and display confirmation message at the button's place

Tags: angular, typescript

As in title, i want to show a button. After the button is clicked, a confirmation message will show right where the button used to be at. If i click yes, it continues to proceed. If i click no, it returns the button

this is my .html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="check(true)">Click</button>
<div *ngIf="isValid">
 <small>Are you sure?</small><a href="#">Yes</a> / <a href="#">No</a>
</div>
```

this is my .ts code:

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
 isValid: boolean = true;
 check(valid: boolean){
  this.isValid = valid;
 }
}
```

Comment: have you been able to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, i followed some hint from @Chris in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `isValid` variable should start out as `false` instead of `true`. Then you can use it to hide the button after it is clicked with `*ngIf="!isValid"` as a directive on the button element.

Is the issue trying to hide the button?

Comment: yes, my issue is to hide the button then show the message.
I apply your suggestion and it displayed both the button and message. Then when i click the button, the message is not shown anymore

Comment: Use a negate operator (!) for toggleing and also you've been missing ngIf on button.

Comment: notice i am saying to add the ngIf on the button element using the (!) operator to hide the button after it is clicked

Answer (score 0):

If originally you want to show the button and on its click, show/hide the underlying message

With isValid property set to true initially, use the following

```
<div *ngIf="isValid; else showMessage">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="check(true)">Click</button>
</div>
<ng-template #showMessage>
 <small>Are you sure?</small><a href="#" >Yes</a> / <a href="#" (click)="check(false)">No</a>
</ng-template
```

Check [Angular2 ngIf-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560088/angular2-ngif-else/44420858#44420858) and https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf for further info

Comment: i don't think this solution really solve my problem. In your solution, if isValid is true, then do the button click, else if it's false, show the message. For my problem, i need a button, which when clicked, hide the button and show a message. Am I understanding this correctly?